# Do we have multiple MAC addresses

Tags: mac-address

Here's a snapshot of ipconfig/all I found

[The LINK](https://forms.swlaw.edu/swlawforms/findmacaddress.htm)

Now, it shows Local Area Connection and Wireless Connection and shows two different physical addresses for both. So are both of these my MAC addresses?

How does it work?

Comment: for a better answer, need more information in your question.

Comment: You can compare a MAC address to the IMEI number of a mobile phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One is the mac for the wireless and one is the mac for the Ethernet.  Each network device has a unique mac

Answer (score 2):

Yes, both are MAC addresses. Every network adaptor has it's own MAC address.

For further information, Wikipedia is a good start: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_address

Answer (score 1):

You got two network adapters, one for wired and one for wireless internet connection. Both show another physical address (=the mac address) because the mac address is kind of 'unique id' for the network card. In the whole world there is only 1 card with the mac address you found. (of course you can spoof these but that was not the question :))